# Maven hibernate - System.out.println doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I created a Maven Project in eclipse and i chose as Archetype webapp-javaee7
with the GroupId : myGroup and ArchetypId : myArchetype.

After I've done that i added the hibernate dependencies :

1. hibernate-core
2. hibernate-annotations
3. hibernate-entity manage
4. postgresql jdbc driver

When i run my application on server it properly shows the Hello World html page
and it also populates the Maven dependencies list with the proper jars.

When i created a class in the package myGroup.myArtifact my System.out.println doesn't work.

```
package myGroup.myArtifact;

public class TestClass {

System.out.println("123");
}
```

I get the following errors : 
"Syntax error on '123' delete this token", Syntax erorr on token(s), misplace construct(s)

This doesn't work either:

```
java.lang.System.out.println("123");
```

My pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>myGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>myArtifact</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: It is underlined with a red line and i got the following errors: syntax error on "123" delete this token, and Syntax erorr on token(s) , misplaced construct(s)

Comment: You can't just put code in a Class like that, it has to be in a method or constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate and Maven related parts of your question are unrelated to your problem.

The problem is that you're trying to execute a function from a place where it doesn't make sense. If you want that `println` to work, you'll need a least a `main` method:

```
public class TestClass {
   public static void main (String[] args)) {
      System.out.println("123");
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, can't believe i missed that.

Comment: Don't be so harsh. It happens haha.